# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ArticlesController#show

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I want to implement ajax in my rails application but I am getting this error.

my erb code where ajax call is made is below

```
<% @articles.each do |article| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= article.title %></td>
      <td><%= article.text %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Show', article_path(article) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_article_path(article) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Show Comment', :action => 'showcomment' ,method: :get, :id =>article, :remote => true ,:class=>'show_comment' %></td>
       <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', article_path(article), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
```

my articles.controller has code

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
    def new
    @article = Article.new
    end

    def create
  @article = Article.new(article_params)

 if @article.save
    redirect_to @article
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end

 def show
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
end

 def edit
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
end
def index
  @articles = Article.all
end

def destroy
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  @article.destroy

  redirect_to articles_path
end

def showcomment
   @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
   @comment = @article.comments.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
end

def update
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])

  if @article.update(article_params)
    redirect_to @article
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
  end
private
  def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
  end

end
```

I dont know somehow the request is getting in show method and it is giving the exception 
Couldn't find Article with 'id'=showcomment

Comment: I'm sorry, but the question is why is this error happening?

Comment: In your view, try passing ":id =>article.id instead".

Comment: i did that and the error got removed but somehow the request doesnt reach showcomment.js.erb

Comment: How is your showcomment.html.erb ?

Answer (score 0):

In your view, try passing:

```
<td><%= link_to 'Show Comment', :action => 'showcomment' ,method: :get, :id =>article.id, :remote => true ,:class=>'show_comment' %>
```

Once the error is removed, try checking if your js template is in the right directory.

P.S: A little thing worth noticing: instead of showcomment use show_comment. Ruby way.